# Windows 7 remote folder access

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

I have in my LAN two Windows 7 computer and I want to access to
shared folders without password and in both computers there is the 
same user name.

How can I do that?

With sharing settings nothing happens!!!

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide more information?  Is it a workgroup or domain?  Are the shared folders on a server or on each PC?  What do you mean by "nothing happens"?  Are you getting error messages?  Damn it Jim, I'm a SysAdmin, not a prognosticator..

Answer (score 2):

> Can you edit your question to provide
>   more information? Is it a workgroup or
>   domain? Are the shared folders on a
>   server or on each PC? What do you mean
>   by "nothing happens"? Are you getting
>   error messages? Damn it Jim, I'm a
>   SysAdmin, not a prognosticator

Damn it, GregD, domain for 2 computers?

**@xdevel2000**, What Do you mean under "without password" the blank password or without entering credentials?

**In Workgroup**

The users on both computers should have the same password (if you do not want to enter password each time when accessing), share folders  and attribute NTFS share permissions to users. If you still get popup requesting credentials, see my answer in:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638862/security-warning-when-opening-file-from-network-share/3435456#3435456

**Homegroup**

For Windows 7 computers it has sense to to set

- http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Create-a-homegroup
- http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/windows7/windows7_homegroup.htm

for single-sign0on accessing files 
In both cases you should create network shares (aka share folders, aka create UNC shares aka
 aka shared folders) and give to shares permissions.

**Domain (the most crazy solution)**

Instructions for sharing on workgroup are valid for domain computers also

### ----------

Let me know if I missed something to help you out and learn myself (any new peculiarities, how to explain and what difficulties usually others encounter)